# Append key/value pair to hash with << in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

In Ruby, one can append values to existing arrays using <<:

```
a = []
a << "foo"
```

but, can you also append key/value pairs to an existing hash?

```
h = {}
h << :key "bar"
```

I know you can do:

```
h[:key] = ""
h[:key] << "bar"
```

but that's not I want.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not `h[:key] = "bar"`?

Comment: This doesn't work: `h[:key] << "bar"`

Answer (score 162, accepted):

There is [`merge!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21).

```
h = {}
h.merge!(key: "bar")
# => {:key=>"bar"}
```

Comment: I don't think `merge!` qualifies as simply creating a new key/value pair as it's actually used for another purpose.

Comment: Good point.  I think it may also end up depending on other factors that the OP didn't post.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Looks like the store method does something similar.  This was mostly an academic question as I've seen << referred as a way to append to arrays but wanted to see if it worked for hashes.  Thanks again.

Comment: The difference is this: `store` simply adds a new pair, it doesn't care if the key already exists. with `merge!` however, entries with duplicate keys are overridden so the method does a bit more than just adding pairs. If you benchmark the two, you will find `store` to be faster(trivial however especially on small hashes)

Comment: @jcarpio Thanks. `Hash#merge!` returns the receiver hash just like `Array#<<` returns the receiver array. `Hash#store` is a completely different thing. Also, with the hash syntax sugar `key: "bar"` in the argument position, I thought this was the closest you can get to your notation. I knew this one is closer to what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was having a problem adding multiple values.   I was trying hash[:a] = 1 hash[:b] = 2  puts hash[:a]  output 1,2

The merge! fixed this issue, now hash[:a]  output 1

Answer (score 106):

Since hashes aren't inherently ordered, there isn't a notion of appending. Ruby hashes since 1.9 maintain insertion order, however. Here are the ways to add new key/value pairs.

The simplest solution is

```
h[:key] = "bar"
```

If you want a method, use `store`:

```
h.store(:key, "bar")
```

If you really, really want to use a "shovel" operator (`<<`), it is actually appending to the value of the hash as an array, and you must specify the key:

```
h[:key] << "bar"
```

The above only works when the key exists. To append a new key, you have to initialize the hash with a default value, which you can do like this:

```
h = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = ''}
h[:key] << "bar"
```

You may be tempted to monkey patch Hash to include a shovel operator that works in the way you've written:

```
class Hash
  def <<(k,v)
    self.store(k,v)
  end
end
```

However, this doesn't inherit the "syntactic sugar" applied to the shovel operator in other contexts:

```
h << :key, "bar" #doesn't work
h.<< :key, "bar" #works
```

Comment: Thorough!  Thanks for the contribution and insight.

Comment: To note, as of Ruby 1.9, Hashes are ordered.

Comment: Ruby 1.9+ maintains insertion order, but a Hash as a data structure doesn't have the concept of any kind of inherent order.

Answer (score 30):

No, I don't think you can append key/value pairs. The only thing *closest* that I am aware of is using the `store` method:

```
h = {}
h.store("key", "value")
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want Hash#merge ?

```
1.9.3p194 :015 > h={}
 => {} 
1.9.3p194 :016 > h.merge(:key => 'bar')
 => {:key=>"bar"} 
1.9.3p194 :017 >
```

If you want to change the array in place use `merge!`

```
1.9.3p194 :016 > h.merge!(:key => 'bar')
 => {:key=>"bar"}
```

Comment: I don't think `merge` it's a good idea because it returns a new array; not adding the new pair to the existing hash.

Comment: How about the `merge!` (i.e. to existing array) instead of `merge` ?

Comment: `merge!` technically works in this context but I think it should be used for merging two hashes rather than simply adding a new pair. Also, if you benchmark `merge!`, it's slower than `store` ;)

Answer (score 4):

Similar as they are, `merge!` and `store` treat *existing* hashes differently depending on keynames, and will therefore affect your preference. Other than that from a syntax standpoint, `merge!`'s `key: "value"` syntax closely matches up against JavaScript and Python. I've always hated comma-separating key-value pairs, personally.

```
hash = {}
hash.merge!(key: "value")
hash.merge!(:key => "value")
puts hash
```

> `{:key=>"value"}`

```
hash = {}
hash.store(:key, "value")
hash.store("key", "value")
puts hash
```

> `{:key=>"value", "key"=>"value"}`

To get the shovel operator `<<` working, I would advise using [Mark Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757193/3543437)'s answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a similar thing but I needed to add values with same keys. When I use merge or update I can't push values with same keys. So I had to use array of hashes.

```
    my_hash_static = {:header =>{:company => 'xx', :usercode => 'xx', :password => 'xx',
                      :type=> 'n:n', :msgheader => from}, :body=>[]}
    my_hash_dynamic = {:mp=>{:msg=>message, :no=>phones} }        
    my_hash_full = my_hash_static[:body].push my_hash_dynamic
```